# Setup MVC2 Web App with IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I've seen SO MANY articles that explain how to do this with IIS6, and some that offer SOME guides for IIS 7 but they are ask you to do so much setup and I've tried them all and ALWAYS get errors.

Is there a guide out there that some of you have used that just...works?

All I need is something step by step to setup my local MVC2 app using my local IIS7 server so I can  test locally without using VS2010's dev server all the time (gets so annoying).

Comment: MVC2 should work seamlessly with IIS7. I run it perfectly fine without making any changes to configuration. What is your error, that will help solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have IIS installed locally you could go to the properties of the project and:

[image]

You may also find the [following blog post](http://iridescence.no/post/Deploying-AspNet-Sites-to-IIS7-from-Visual-Studio.aspx) useful.

Comment: Whenever I try that and then try and navigate to the page, it always gives me some errors with my web.config about like all these different things.

Comment: @slandau, do you think that `it always gives me some errors with my web.config about like all these different things` is a problem description?

Comment: Not at all. But I'm posting this from another location at the moment so I'm unable to grab the exact errors from the page, and I was hoping that someone might have ran into an issue with a web.config as well when emulating this exact process that might be able to pinpoint the errors I was having without seeing them.

Comment: @slandau, works fine for me. I just check this radio button in the properties and everything works as expected.

Comment: Maybe I will setup a new project and try that. Maybe some settings got messed up from me trying to go about it in another way.